# Whats the name of this algorithm?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, traversal

Hi im working with a bidiminsional array , and i want to go trough every cell.
First i start from the top left corner ,then i will verify if im in a corner because im going to check their neighbours, lastly im going  to finish at the bottom right corner. 
I have seen this type of solution for two-dimensional array repeated several times in various problems. I would like to know the specific name of the algorithm and if you could give me some link with the information

The algorithm doesnt not concer neather backtracking nor recursion

Comment: it is standard two-dimensional array traversal, it is not algorithm per se

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean an algorithm of the following type:

```
for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++) {
        // Do something with a[row][col];
    }
}
```

If yes this is mostly called *array iteration* or *array traversal*. If you want to emphasize the dimension of the array you can call it f.e. *2D array traversal*

Note: To make your question better understandable by users I would recommend to provide a short code example next time.